# selenium click on header "Usage" button

Tags: python, selenium, scrape

Need help.  I get error : ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

I am using the following selenium code and I believe find_element() is finding the button.   But when I click on it I get error... help?

```
# Select Usage button 
eButton = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Usage menu']")
eButton.click()
```

The header has 4 buttons.   Below is the html for the 1st 2 buttons:

PS. I am trying to scrape my data usage info from t-mobile web site.  I am able to login, pw and get to main page.   I am able to get to usage by browser.get('https://t-mobile/usage') after logging in.   But want to understand how html click could work???

Full nav bar header is included below.

```
<div>
  <a id="digital-header-logo-url" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="ntm-navbar__brand ng-star-inserted" href="https://www.t-mobile.com/account/dashboard" target="_self">
    <picture class="tmo-unav-logo">
      <source media="(max-width: 1023px)" srcset="https://cdn.tmobile.com/content/dam/t-mobile/ntm/branding/logos/corporate/tmo-logo-v3.svg">
        <img id="digital-header-logo-img" alt="T-MOBILE" src="https://cdn.tmobile.com/content/dam/t-mobile/ntm/branding/logos/corporate/tmo-logo-v3.svg"/>
      </source>
    </picture>
  </a>
  <!---->
  <div class="ntm-navbar__hamburger-container">
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <div class="ntm-navbar__hamburger-links ng-star-inserted" id="call-us-mobile">
      <a tmodigitalanalytics="" class="nav__link tmo_tfn_number ng-star-inserted" id="digital-header-utility-mobile-1" href="https://www.t-mobile.com/account/contact-us " target="_self">
        <tmo-unav-icon matbadgecolor="warn" matbadgesize="small" class="mat-badge mdi navbar__cart-item mat-badge-warn mat-badge-overlap mat-badge-above mat-badge-after mat-badge-small mat-badge-hidden ng-star-inserted loaded" data-icon="communication/phone.svg">
          <span class="masked-icon ng-star-inserted" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.styleguide.t-mobile.com/sdk/v2/svg-icons/communication/phone.svg&quot;);"/>
          <!---->
          <!---->
        </tmo-unav-icon>
        <!---->
        <!---->
      </a>
      <!---->
      <!---->
      <!---->
      <!---->
      <!---->
    </div>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <button tmodigitalanalytics="" eventdata="{&quot;navType&quot;: &quot;hnav&quot; , &quot;category&quot;:&quot;Menu&quot;}" aria-label="menu" id="digital-header-menu-button" class="ntm-navbar__hamburger ng-star-inserted"><tmo-unav-icon icon="navigation/menu.svg" class="mdi loaded" data-icon="navigation/menu.svg"><span class="masked-icon ng-star-inserted" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.styleguide.t-mobile.com/sdk/v2/svg-icons/navigation/menu.svg&quot;);"/><!----><!----></tmo-unav-icon>  </button>
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
  <div class="navbar__collapse navbar__collapse--default-menu is-hidden">
    <div class="navbar__collapse--slide">
      <!---->
      <div class="navbar__collapse--container ng-star-inserted">
        <tmo-unav-dropdown-container _nghost-serverapp-c120="">
          <div class="ntm-navbar__nav ntm-navbar__nav--left">
            <tmo-unav-dropdown _nghost-serverapp-c121="" class="ng-tns-c121-49 ntm-navbar--dark ng-star-inserted" id="nav-link-contaniner-0">
              <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="navbar__item ng-tns-c121-49">
                <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="nav__link-container ng-tns-c121-49 ng-star-inserted">
                  <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="nav__link ng-tns-c121-49" id="digital-header-nav-link-head-0" href="https://my.t-mobile.com/billandpay" target="_self"> Bill &amp; pay <!----><!----></a>
                  <button _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav__link caret-icon ng-tns-c121-49 ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Bill &amp; pay menu" id="digital-header-nav-link-caret-0" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                    <!---->
                  </button>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </div>
                <!---->
              </div>
            </tmo-unav-dropdown>
            <tmo-unav-dropdown _nghost-serverapp-c121="" class="ng-tns-c121-50 ntm-navbar--dark ng-star-inserted" id="nav-link-contaniner-1">
              <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="navbar__item ng-tns-c121-50">
                <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="nav__link-container ng-tns-c121-50 ng-star-inserted">
                  <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="nav__link ng-tns-c121-50" id="digital-header-nav-link-head-1" href="https://www.t-mobile.com/usage" target="_self"> Usage <!----><!----></a>
                  <button _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav__link caret-icon ng-tns-c121-50 ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Usage menu" id="digital-header-nav-link-caret-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                    <!---->
                  </button>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </div>
                <!---->
              </div>
            </tmo-unav-dropdown>
            <tmo-unav-dropdown _nghost-serverapp-c121="" class="ng-tns-c121-51 ntm-navbar--dark ng-star-inserted" id="nav-link-contaniner-2">
              <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="navbar__item ng-tns-c121-51">
                <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="nav__link-container ng-tns-c121-51 ng-star-inserted">
                  <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="nav__link ng-tns-c121-51" id="digital-header-nav-link-head-2" href="https://my.t-mobile.com/account/account-overview" target="_self"> Account <!----><!----></a>
                  <button _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav__link caret-icon ng-tns-c121-51 ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Account menu" id="digital-header-nav-link-caret-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                    <!---->
                  </button>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </div>
                <!---->
              </div>
            </tmo-unav-dropdown>
            <tmo-unav-dropdown _nghost-serverapp-c121="" class="ng-tns-c121-52 ntm-navbar--dark last-dropdown ng-star-inserted" id="nav-link-contaniner-3">
              <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="navbar__item ng-tns-c121-52">
                <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="nav__link-container ng-tns-c121-52 ng-star-inserted">
                  <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="nav__link ng-tns-c121-52" id="digital-header-nav-link-head-3" href="https://my.t-mobile.com/purchase/shop" target="_self"> Shop <!----><!----></a>
                  <button _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav__link caret-icon ng-tns-c121-52 ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Shop menu" id="digital-header-nav-link-caret-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                    <!---->
                  </button>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </div>
                <!---->
              </div>
            </tmo-unav-dropdown>
            <!---->
          </div>
        </tmo-unav-dropdown-container>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar__collapse--container container--grey ng-star-inserted">
        <div class="ntm-navbar__nav ntm-navbar__nav--right">
          <div class="navbar__item ng-star-inserted" id="call-us || 'navbar-item-0' ">
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
          </div>
          <!---->
          <tmo-unav-dropdown _nghost-serverapp-c121="" class="ng-tns-c121-53 ntm-navbar--dark ng-star-inserted" id="digital-header-utility-0">
            <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="navbar__item ng-tns-c121-53">
              <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="nav__link-container ng-tns-c121-53 ng-star-inserted">
                <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="nav__link ng-tns-c121-53 nav-right-with-dropdown" id="digital-header-nav-link-head-utility-0" href="https://www.t-mobile.com/account/contact-us" target="_self">
                  <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="nav-item-with-icon ng-tns-c121-53 ng-star-inserted" id="digital-header-nav-link-head-content-utility-0">
                    <tmo-unav-icon _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="mdi message-icon ng-tns-c121-53 loaded" id="call-usLpMessage" data-icon="communication/chat_bubble.svg">
                      <span class="masked-icon ng-star-inserted" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.styleguide.t-mobile.com/sdk/v2/svg-icons/communication/chat_bubble.svg&quot;);"/>
                      <!---->
                      <!---->
                    </tmo-unav-icon>
                    <span _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="d-inline show-on-sm-modal ng-tns-c121-53"> Contact &amp; support </span>
                  </div>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </a>
                <button _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav__link caret-icon ng-tns-c121-53 ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Contact &amp; support menu" id="digital-header-nav-link-caret-utility-0" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0">
                  <tmo-unav-icon _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="mdi ng-tns-c121-53 ng-star-inserted" data-icon="navigation/expand_more.svg">
                    <!---->
                  </tmo-unav-icon>
                  <!---->
                </button>
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="dropdown__menu ng-tns-c121-53 nav-right-dropdown ng-trigger ng-trigger-centerX ng-star-inserted" aria-expanded="false" style="left: 2px; height: 0px; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="ng-tns-c121-53 livePersonLink ng-star-inserted" target="_self" tabindex="0" id="lpUnavLink" style="">
                    <!---->
                  </a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="ng-tns-c121-53 dropdown__item ng-star-inserted" href="https://www.t-mobile.com/account/contact-us" target="_self" tabindex="0" id="call-us" style="">
                    <span _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="ng-tns-c121-53 ng-star-inserted">Contact us</span>
                    <!---->
                  </a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="ng-tns-c121-53 dropdown__item ng-star-inserted" href="https://my.t-mobile.com/myphone/checkorder.html" target="_self" tabindex="0" style="">
                    <span _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="ng-tns-c121-53 ng-star-inserted">Check order status</span>
                    <!---->
                  </a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="ng-tns-c121-53 dropdown__item ng-star-inserted" href="https://www.t-mobile.com/support" target="_self" tabindex="0" style="">
                    <span _ngcontent-serverapp-c121="" class="ng-tns-c121-53 ng-star-inserted">Help &amp; support</span>
                    <!---->
                  </a>
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                  <!---->
                </div>
                <!---->
                <!---->
              </div>
              <!---->
            </div>
          </tmo-unav-dropdown>
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <div class="navbar__item navbar__item-search-bar ng-star-inserted" id="search || 'navbar-item-2' ">
            <!---->
            <div class="navbar__collapse--search-bar search__bar-inline ng-star-inserted" aria-hidden="true">
              <tmo-search-bar componentid="desktop" class="ntm-navbar--dark">
                <div id="navbar_search" class="navbar__search ng-star-inserted">
                  <form novalidate="" role="search" autocomplete="off" action="." class="navbar__search-form ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" id="nav_search_form-desktop">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mat-form-field ng-tns-c111-62 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-outline mat-form-field-can-float ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted">
                      <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c111-62">
                        <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c111-62">
                          <div class="mat-form-field-outline ng-tns-c111-62 ng-star-inserted">
                            <div class="mat-form-field-outline-start ng-tns-c111-62" style="width: 0px;"/>
                            <div class="mat-form-field-outline-gap ng-tns-c111-62" style="width: 0px;"/>
                            <div class="mat-form-field-outline-end ng-tns-c111-62"/>
                          </div>
                          <div class="mat-form-field-outline mat-form-field-outline-thick ng-tns-c111-62 ng-star-inserted">
                            <div class="mat-form-field-outline-start ng-tns-c111-62" style="width: 0px;"/>
                            <div class="mat-form-field-outline-gap ng-tns-c111-62" style="width: 0px;"/>
                            <div class="mat-form-field-outline-end ng-tns-c111-62"/>
                          </div>
                          <!---->
                          <!---->
                          <div class="mat-form-field-prefix ng-tns-c111-62 ng-star-inserted">
                            <button type="button" mat-icon-button="" matprefix="" tmodigitalanalytics="" aria-label="Search" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-icon-button mat-button-base ng-tns-c111-62">
                              <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
                                <tmo-unav-icon aria-hidden="true" icon="action/search.svg" class="mdi loaded" data-icon="action/search.svg">
                                  <span class="masked-icon ng-star-inserted" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.styleguide.t-mobile.com/sdk/v2/svg-icons/action/search.svg&quot;);"/>
                                  <!---->
                                  <!---->
                                </tmo-unav-icon>
                              </span>
                              <span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple mat-button-ripple-round"/>
                              <span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"/>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <!---->
                          <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c111-62">
                            <label class="sr-only ng-tns-c111-62" for="nav_search_input-desktop">Search</label>
                            <input matinput="" formcontrolname="searchTerm" name="nav_search_input" type="search" role="combobox" required="" oninput="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase()" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control navbar__search-form-input ng-tns-c111-62 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" aria-required="true" aria-activedescendant="" placeholder="Search" id="nav_search_input-desktop" data-placeholder="Search"/>
                            <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c111-62">
                              <!---->
                            </span>
                          </div>
                          <!---->
                        </div>
                        <!---->
                        <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c111-62">
                          <!---->
                          <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c111-62 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">
                            <!---->
                            <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c111-62"/>
                          </div>
                          <!---->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </form>
                  <div class="navbar__search-results ng-star-inserted">
                    <div cdktrapfocus="" class="navbar__search-results-container">
                      <div class="navbar__search-results-default ng-star-inserted">
                        <ul role="listbox">
                          <!---->
                          <li class="search__results-tile ng-star-inserted">
                            <span class="eyebrow">POPULAR</span>
                            <ul class="search__results-links">
                              <!---->
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <!---->
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <!---->
                      <!---->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!---->
                </div>
                <!---->
              </tmo-search-bar>
            </div>
            <!---->
            <a role="button" href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav__link ng-star-inserted" id="digital-header-utility-2" aria-expanded="false">
              <tmo-unav-icon class="mdi loaded" data-icon="action/search.svg">
                <span class="masked-icon ng-star-inserted" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.styleguide.t-mobile.com/sdk/v2/svg-icons/action/search.svg&quot;);"/>
                <!---->
                <!---->
              </tmo-unav-icon>
              <span class="d-inline show-on-sm-modal ng-star-inserted"> Search </span>
              <!---->
              <tmo-unav-icon icon="navigation/chevron_right.svg" class="ntm-arrow mdi show-sm" data-icon="navigation/chevron_right.svg">
                <!---->
              </tmo-unav-icon>
            </a>
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <!---->
          </div>
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <div class="navbar__item navbar__item-button navbar__item-login ng-star-inserted">
            <button id="user-links-dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav__link nav__link-button dropdown-toggles nav__link-button-desktop MAGENTA" aria-expanded="false"> My account <tmo-unav-icon class="mdi loaded" data-icon="hardware/keyboard_arrow_down.svg"><span class="masked-icon ng-star-inserted" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.styleguide.t-mobile.com/sdk/v2/svg-icons/hardware/keyboard_arrow_down.svg&quot;);"/><!----><!----></tmo-unav-icon></button>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar__collapse--container container--grey navbar__collapse--universal-menu ng-star-inserted">
        <p class="navbar__item"/>
        <ul class="ntm-navbar__nav ntm-navbar__nav--right ntm-navbar__nav-universal-menu-right">
          <!---->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!---->
      <!---->
      <!---->
      <!---->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar__collapse navbar__collapse--login-menu notSticky" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <tmo-log-in-menu _nghost-serverapp-c114="" class="ntm-navbar--dark ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c114="" class="login__dropdown">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c114="" class="login__dropdown-buttons--secondary last-item-height ng-star-inserted">
          <!---->
          <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c114="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="nav__link ng-star-inserted" id="user-link-dropdown-item-category-name-0-0-0" href="https://my.t-mobile.com/account/profile" target="_self"> Profile </a>
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c114="" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="nav__link ng-star-inserted" id="user-link-dropdown-item-category-name-0-0-1" href="https://www.t-mobile.com/account-activity" target="_self"> Account activity </a>
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <a _ngcontent-serverapp-c114="" href="javascript:void(0)" tmodigitalanalytics="" class="nav__link ng-star-inserted" id="user-link-dropdown-item-category-name-0-0-3" target="_self"> Logout</a>
          <!---->
          <!---->
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
      </div>
    </tmo-log-in-menu>
    <!---->
  </div>
  <!---->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of the html source? Perhaps there is an iframe surrounding this code, that you'd need to switch into. Or a number of other things

Comment: @C.Peck -- full nav header html has been added.

Comment: tried several solutions per below.  I'm using jupyter so while page is visible... I tried to hover over header nav element : [tm.browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ntm-navbar__menu-bar") ] no error. 

then I tried to hover over the Usage buttong : [elm = tm.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Usage menu']")] - no error... (so finding the button)

But when I click... it return element not interactable.

Comment: FYI, I seem to solve by hovering the mouse over the area and then elementButtong.click(). This seemed to work.  Will close this out.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible issues that can cause the error you mentioned.
Since we can't debug your actual code, only guess the most possible options are:

1. You need to add a delay.
   Possibly waiting for the element to become clickable will help here.
   If so, please try this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Usage menu']"))).click()
```

2. The element can be out of visible view port.
   If so scrolling to the element and then clicking on it should help.
   Something like this will do the job:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Usage menu']")))
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
element.click()
```

Comment: Tried this and click still results in error : ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable.  (see comments above)

Answer (score 0):

The target element in the above HTML snippet is a hidden element.
In the element HTML tag, you can see the attribute `aria-hidden="true"` which means this is a hidden element.

My suggestions are :

1. Check if the XPATH `//button[@aria-label='Usage menu']` is pointing to the expected element. There might be another element matching the same XPATH which is not hidden.
2. If the element XPATH is correct even after checking #1 above, fire the action through the JavaScript executor.

Using JavaScript executor to click on the element.

```py
eButton = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Usage menu']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", eButton)
```

Comment: Tried  JavaScript executor per above... failed that it could not find element.

Comment: In your example code above in the question, you have used the same XPATH for the element. And in there you are getting an ElementNotInteractable issue. Not the "no element found" issue as you are mentioning now? Bit confused on the contradicting statements.

Comment: Also, have you tried the suggestion #1 above?

Comment: I believe I tried all suggestions.  Finally when with hovering the mouse over the area and then elementButtong.click().  This seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with
hovering the mouse over the area and then elementButtong.click(). This seemed to work.